# Values are updating if we click on anywhere in page

Tags: javascript, php, css, magento

we are using magento multi vendor site.

We are using following code to display Price and Special Price in frontend

i am facing some issues

1)once we edit price and special price text field and click on anywhere on page, its updating values.

It should update only when we click on update button.

2)If we edit only Price, than "updated" message is displaying under both "price and special price"

3)once cursor is in the text field, than we can not able to refresh the page.

**Price - HTMl**

```
<span class="label pro_status">
 <?php //echo $products->getPrice(); ?>                              
 <input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" onchange="updateFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>')" style = ""/>

 <p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
 <br/>
</span>
```

**Special Price - HTML**

```
<span class="label pro_status"> 
<?php ?> 

<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "specialprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?>" onchange="updateFieldSpecialPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>')" style = ""/> 

<p id="updatedspecialprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p> 
<br/> 
</span>
```

**Price - Javascript**

```
function updateFieldPrice(product_id)
    {
    var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id;
    var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id;
    var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldPrice/')?>';
    $price = $wk_jq(priceId).val();
    new Ajax.Request(url, {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price},
    onComplete: function (transport) {
    //alert(transport.responseText);

    jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut();

    }
    });
    }
```

**Special Price - Javascript**

```
function updateFieldSpecialPrice(product_id) 
{ 
var priceId = '#specialprice_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedspecialprice_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldSpecialPrice/')?>'; 
$price = $wk_jq(priceId).val(); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 
parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 
jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 
} 
}); 
}
```

Comment: There should only be one question, not three.

Comment: @JohnBarça you are right, but once i post question than until for next 90 minutes, i can not able to post one more question. but i have already millions of problem, so i posted three.

Comment: any plugin conflict, any error shows in console?

Comment: no, its our own customized code. some problems in above code

Comment: try changing your <p> tag to span or div

Comment: put alert() at all significant point and see which is error line....

Comment: @profile-101 jQuery(updatedqty) or $wk_jq(priceId), which is set? plz check it. jQuery or $wk_jq

Comment: @yjs we are using this : jQuery(updatedqty)

Comment: so have to use this one also; jQuery(priceId)

Comment: i am new to js can you please give complete line of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `onblur` 
price

```
<span class="label pro_status">
 <?php //echo $products->getPrice(); ?>                              
 <input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" onblur="updateFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>')" style = ""/>


 <p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
 <br/>
</span>
```

special price

```
<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "specialprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?>" onblur="updateFieldSpecialPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>')" style = ""/>
```

Comment: but in that page , lot of  other codes are there, they are using onclick function

Comment: still same result, can you please check here : http://2.kidsdial.com/index.php/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/

Comment: did not any problem with  me all is working showing single update and refresh the browser too

Comment: please chnage any product MRP and click the mouse below textfield, dont click on update button, but still its updating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98207/discussion-between-profile-101-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: can you please check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334130/textfield-is-hiding-once-we-click-on-cancel-button

Comment: please check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435234/attribute-is-not-saving-in-database

Comment: please check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435534/magento-remove-edit-button-and-make-it-editable-once-we-click-on-textfield