# Textfield is hiding once we click on cancel button

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento

we are using magento multi vendor site

we are using following code to update and cancel price . but once we click on "cancel" button textfield is hiding.

**PHTML**

```
<span class="label pro_status">
 <?php //echo $products->getPrice(); ?>                              
 <input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = ""/>


 <p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
 <br/>

 <button id="price_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="update" onclick="updateFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" >
 <span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
 </button>


     <button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;">
     <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
     </button>

    </span>
```

**Javascript**

```
function hideResetPrice(product_id) {

var qtyId='#price_'+ product_id;
var editLink="#price_edit_link_"+ product_id;
var updateButton="#price_update_button_"+ product_id;
var valueprice="#valueprice_"+ product_id;
var resetButton="#price_reset_button_"+ product_id;

$wk_jq(qtyId).hide();
$wk_jq(valueprice).show();
$wk_jq(editLink).show();
$wk_jq(updateButton).hide();
$wk_jq(resetButton).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove  this line `$wk_jq(qtyId).hide();` because on cancel you are hiding `input field` in function.

```
function hideResetPrice(product_id,priceold) {

    var qtyId='#price_'+ product_id;
    var editLink="#price_edit_link_"+ product_id;
    var updateButton="#price_update_button_"+ product_id;
    var valueprice="#valueprice_"+ product_id;
    var resetButton="#price_reset_button_"+ product_id;


    $wk_jq(valueprice).show();
     $wk_jq(qtyId).val(priceold);
    $wk_jq(editLink).show();

    }
```

```
<?php //echo $products->getPrice(); ?>                              
 <input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = ""/>




<p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
 <br/>

 <button id="price_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="update" onclick="updateFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" >
 <span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
 </button>


     <button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
     <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
     </button>

    </span>
```

Comment: now textfield is not becoming blank. but "update and cancel" button become disappear once we click on "cancel" button

Comment: what you want to do on cancel button?

Comment: if we click on cancel button it shoul display original price inside textfield and update and cancel button should not disappear.

Comment: update the html and script too kindly replace and feedback me

Comment: one small problem is there.

once we update the price and click on " update" button. its saving in database.

but if we click on cancel button, its showing old price. 

but if we click on cancel button after refreshing the page, its showing updated price.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98232/discussion-between-qaisar-satti-and-profile-101).

Answer (score 1):

```
*There is a minor mistake you are doing with the Cancel button.*
```

You are **calling hideResetPrice()** function on click of cancel button.
Just **remove onclick="hideResetPrice()** function. 
And **let the code be** 
 only. 
This will not hide your text field.

```
<button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products>getId(); ?>'); return false;">
 <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
 </button>
```

Comment: Just check it and let me know :)

Comment: i solved this before with help of  above answer. i will surely contact you for other problems. i upvoted for it